# Projecting on a std::map with std::ranges::min

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Is it possible to project on a std::map? I tried to use std::ranges::min with a projection, but it seems to throw errors that I can't interpret why its not liking things.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges> 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> usage_table;
    auto lowest = std::ranges::min( std::move(usage_table), 
                                   {}, 
                                   &std::map<int,int>::value_type::second );
}
```

I could work around it, but it would be nice if this one liner worked.

Best

Comment: Please share the error message as well. Do you mean to use `min_element` instead?

Comment: What does it mean 'to project' in this context?

Comment: I cannot check it from here, but do you still get errors of you remove the move statement?

Comment: ranges development is not mature yet. Maybe could be a bug or a not implemented function.

Comment: Its a very long error message, something about an invocable. The projection I'm referring to is on the third parameter, on how you can "project" to a member variable of the value type of the map container. If I remove the hard move it makes no difference. The min + pipe looks cool.

Comment: @AdamZahran, Instead of the element being used in the algorithm, a projection is used. For example, instead of summing customers, you can sum their balances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `std::ranges::min` you can use `std::ranges::min_element` like this:

```
auto lowest = *std::ranges::min_element(std::move(usage_table), 
                                        {}, 
                                        &std::map<int,int>::value_type::second);
```

Also, it's unclear why you are `move`ing the `map`, it doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: Depends on what you want no? What's wrong with using [`std::ranges::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min)?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, it does seem it should work. See the edit :) I removed the bit that said it's wrong. But I can't actually seem to get it to compile :(

Comment: ranges implementations are not mature. It could be a case of bug/not implemented feature

Comment: @bolov Yes, that's certainly possible as well.

Comment: It looks like it compiles without the move, with the move it min_element produces a std::ranges::dangling, without the it produces at iterator. It does the correct thing when I remove the move! Thank you.

Comment: @mriera Please see the other answer if you haven't already. It explains much very clearly what's going on, and suggests alternatives.

Answer (score 10):

Look at [`std::ranges::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min)'s function signature:

```
template< ranges::input_range R, class Proj = std::identity,
          std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
              std::projected<ranges::iterator_t<R>, Proj>> Comp = ranges::less >
requires std::indirectly_copyable_storable<ranges::iterator_t<R>, ranges::range_value_t<R>*>
constexpr ranges::range_value_t<R> min( R&& r, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {} );
```

It returns `range_value_t<R>` which imply the `value_type` of range need be `copyable`, so `ranges::min` requires `indirectly_copyable_storable` which requires `indirectly_copyable` which requires  [`indirectly_writable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_writable):

```
template<class Out, class T>
  concept indirectly_writable =
    requires(Out&& o, T&& t) {
      *o = std::forward<T>(t);
      *std::forward<Out>(o) = std::forward<T>(t);
      const_cast<const std::iter_reference_t<Out>&&>(*o) = std::forward<T>(t);
      const_cast<const std::iter_reference_t<Out>&&>(*std::forward<Out>(o)) =
        std::forward<T>(t);
    };
```

We need `*o = std::forward<T>(t)` be valid expression which `Out` is `range_value_t<R>*` which is `std::pair<const int, int>*`, but this is not possible since we can't assign a `std::pair<const int, int>` to other:

```
std::pair<const int, int> a, b;
// use of deleted function 'std::pair<const int, int>& std::pair<const int, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const int, int>&)'
a = b;
```

So unfortunately, `std::ranges::min` cannot apply in `std::map`:

```
// constraints not satisfied
std::ranges::min(std::map<int, int>{});
```

But if you want to find `std::map`'s minimum value of its `key_type/mapped_type`, you can just use c++20 range adaptor [`std::views::keys/values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), it works fine with `std::ranges::min`:

```
std::map<int, int> usage_table{{5, -12}, {3, 4}};
// -12
auto lowest = std::ranges::min(usage_table | std::views::values);
```

Comment: Good find! Strange that they made such a difference between `std::ranges:min`(max/minmax) and `std::ranges::min_element`(max_element/minmax_element)

Comment: @JHBonarius, `min` returns an actual value (not by reference) whereas `min_element` returns an iterator.

Comment: @chris, true, but using projection that value can be a copyable type again... So it in theory should work... I think this will have to be fixed in a future update of the standard. I think the concept of projection is just too new, so this are early adaptation issues.

Comment: @JHBonarius, Yes, I wouldn't be surprised if something was overlooked.